# How to structure a package in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij and all I want to is basically set up my folders in my IDE like the instructor has in his workspace but Intellij get weird when I try to set it like that. I've tried placing the example class directly under the data structure folder but it won't let me and i've tried placing the treehouse folder inside the com folder but it won't let me.

[image: My intellij]

How I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

Answer (score 0):

Open **Data structure** folder instead of Second.

For that you go to *File -> Open... -> choose Data structure folder*.